# Pandas groupby SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, pandas

I was doing a simple groupby, but got a deprecation / future warning message.

Here's my original groupby, which works 100% OK:

```
print(df)

   customer_ID  amount
0          joe     321
1          joe       5
2          joe       1
3          joe    3135
4         mary      35
5         mary      65
6         mary      68
7         mary     654
8         mary       1
9         john    5313
10        john      51
11        john     351
12        john      84
13        john      68

df.groupby('customer_ID')['amount'].agg({'count_transactions':'count','median_spend':'median'})

             count_transactions  median_spend
customer_ID                                  
joe                           4           163
john                          5            84
mary                          5            65

FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use named aggregation instead.

>>> grouper.agg(name_1=func_1, name_2=func_2)
```

So I decided to try their suggestion, which is `grouper.agg(name_1=func_1, name_2=func_2)`

But when I try the suggested method I get a `SyntaxError`:

```
df.groupby('customer_ID')['amount'].agg('count_transactions'=count,'median_spend'=median)

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I've tried a few variations of this, such as adding / removing quotations, but can't figure out how to solve it.

I know my first groupby works fine.. but I'd still like to know where I'm going wrong with the suggestion from the future warning message.

Comment: `count_transactions=count` instead of `'count_transactions'=count`

Comment: @Asocia that just gives me a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: You also need to remove the quotes around `median_spend`.

Comment: Yep, did that. `df.groupby('customer_ID')['amount'].agg({count_transactions=count,median_spend=median})`   gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `df.groupby('customer_ID')['amount'].agg(count_transactions=count,median_spend=median)`

Comment: Ok, looks like I had to add quotes around `count` and `median`. This works now: `t.groupby('customer_ID')['amount'].agg(count_transactions='count',median_spend='median')`

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a `SyntaxError`, it can't be related with `pandas`. You can get the same error with this:

```
>>> print("Hello", 'end'="")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

So the problem is with the quotes around keyword argument. You need to remove them.

You could also get rid of deprecation warning by unpacking your `dict` with `**`.

This

```
df.groupby('customer_ID')['amount'].agg(**{'count_transactions':'count','median_spend':'median'})
```

will work as same as this one:

```
df.groupby('customer_ID')['amount'].agg(count_transactions='count',median_spend='median')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the functions have to be strings.

I had to add quotes around `count` and `median` functions, and remove quotes from new column names `count_transactions` and `median_spend`.

Solution:

```
df.groupby('customer_ID')['amount'].agg(count_transactions='count',median_spend='median')
```